# How does Django know what values to put in the test database

Tags: django, testing

I know that it doesn't use my development db because I deleted all offending cases, so how does Django do it? Is it just inserting random values, or does it somehow understand the test case I've written and tries to make it fail? Is it guaranteed that passing a test means my code is flawless, as far as that functionality is concerned?

Answer (score 2):

Django does a setup/teardown of a blank database with the same schema, it's up to *you* as the developer to give yourself adequate test data, mostly through the use of [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#fixture-loading).

Tests by no means mean your code is **flawless**, unit tests are only as good as you write them to be.

Reference:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/

Comment: To generate test data you can also use apps like: https://github.com/paulocheque/django-dynamic-fixture https://github.com/coagulant/django-whatever